# Getting empty value in SKProduct array in iOS 17

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, ios17, skproduct

I have this issue in iOS 17 only and it gets the intended value in iOS 16.
I have this variable `@Published var products: [SKProduct] = []`
when I try to execute the following function

```
func getProduct(packageId: Int?) -> SKProduct? {
    switch packageId{
    case 1:
        return products.first(where: {$0.productIdentifier == IAPConstant.weeklyPremium})
    case 2:
        return products.first(where: {$0.productIdentifier == IAPConstant.yearlyPremium})
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

the code in case of iOS 17 returns 'nil' i.e.

```
(lldb) po selectedProduct
 nil
```

the same code in case of iOS 16 returns this:

```
(lldb) po selectedProduct
▿ Optional<SKProduct>
- some : <SKProduct: 0x600001258bc0>
```

I am clueless why it's happening in iOS 17 only. Any complete/temporary fix would be appreciated as it has stopped the in app purchase for iOS 17 users.

Comment: I'm having same issue. It sometimes has a product value but sometimes not. Just because of that Apple is rejecting the app. Purchase screen doesn't appear time-by-time. I think it's an Apple bug as usual.